# React: Handling an onChange within mapping render

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, sorting

I have created a matrix/table using material ui and have also used a button toggle to select a value.

The table is a matrix where a member can see what their current membership is, and they can choose from other membership types based on age... seniors, juniors, infants.

https://codesandbox.io/s/64j65yrxpw

The demo above will give more clarity. The issue is that when I select an option of yes, no or maybe - all options across all people are selected rather than just that person in that row and across all membership types - (click an option and you will see the problem).

The below is what feeds the table:

```
const selected = [
  { personId: "0001657", fullName: "Joe Bloggs", seniorStatus: "Yes" },
  { personId: "0001666", fullName: "John Doe", seniorStatus: "No" }
];
```

and ideally will want something like this returned based on selections:

```
 const newlySelected = [
   { personId: "0001657", fullName: "Joe Bloggs", seniorStatus: "Yes", juniors: "maybe" },
   { personId: "0001666", fullName: "John Doe", seniorStatus: "No", juniors: "no", infants: "yes" },
 ];
```

I appreciate that there are two issues here... the toggle not behaving individually and the return of desired json - any help would be awesome. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a "too simple" `state`.

```
state = {
  alignment: "left",
  formats: ["bold"]
};
```

Your `state.alignment` used by all buttons. If you want to keep it in the form of single component you need to make it 2D array:

```
[
  ['<#1 btn value>', '<#2 btn value', ...],
  [..., ..., ...]
]
```

Then when you call `setState` you need to change the relevant item in the 2D array based on the action location. You have to indexes, one of the row, one of the cell, you can use them.

**UPDATE**
New state - 2D array

```
value: [
  ["no", "no", "no"],
  ["no", "no", "no"]
]
```

New ToggleButtonGroup - using rowIdx and cellIdx to have the right position in the 2D array

```
<ToggleButtonGroup
  className={classes.toggleButtonGroup}
  value={value[rowIdx][cellIdx]}
  exclusive
  onChange={(event, val) => this.handleValue(event, val, rowIdx, cellIdx)}
>
```

New handleValue - using the rowIdx, cellIdx to change the value in the right position.

```
handleValue = (event, val, rowIdx, cellIdx) => {
  const newValue = [...this.state.value]
  newValue[rowIdx][cellIdx] = val
  this.setState({
    value: newValue,
  })
}
```

Comment: Yes just looked into this, not sure how to implement in my case - will need to work it out

Comment: Could you help at all with the demo... please!

Comment: state = {
    value: [["no", "yes", "maybe"]]
  };

Comment: thanks! where do I add the [rowIdx][cellIdx] as not defined currently

Comment: @TomRudge `rowIdx` replaces the idx of the selected => TableRow and `cellIdx` of the MEMBESHIP => TableCell

Comment: Thank you - been a great help - still a long way to go but great

Comment: @TomRudge Do the official react.js tutorial, will fill up many gaps: https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html